# Indexed property in Delphi - beginner is making multiple Player objects accessible in a Game object

Tags: delphi

I am a beginner Delphi user. I have this while loop and instead of only one player (player1) , I would like to have many players, written as Player[i]. I have edited my class where it lets me add the [I]

```
   while i < FMyPlayers.TeamCount do
    begin
       buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Placeing Unit: '+FMyPlayers.Player[i].Values['name']+'.',mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);
          if buttonSelected = mrCancel then exit;
       imageyouwant.LoadFromFile(thisdir+'\char\'+FMyPlayers.Player[i].Values['picon']);
       Hexmap1.ImageAHex(ImageYouWant , bsSolid, position);
       FMyPlayers.Player[i].Add('pos='+inttostr(position.x)+inttostr(position.Y));
       FMyPlayers.PlaceUnit := false;
    end;
```

But now in my class i get error on

```
      property Player: array[1..20] of TStringList read P;
```

my MYPlayer Class is as follows

```
TPlayers = class
Private
  p : array[1..20] of TStringList;
  FPlaceUnit: Boolean;
  FTeamCount: Integer;
Public
  property Player: array[1..20] of TStringList read P;
  property PlaceUnit : Boolean read FPlaceUnit write FPlaceUnit;
  procedure AddPlayer (PlayerNo : integer; player : String);
  property TeamCount : Integer read FTeamCount write FTeamCount;

 constructor Create;   virtual;
End;
```

Comment: You want to change FMyPlayers class (definition not shown) from whatever it is, to an array of whatever it is?  We like to see some effort. And show your types.  What is FMyPlayerPlayer1 declared as? Try changing it to FMyPlayers:TObjectList<Whatever>.

Comment: Still kind of new at creating my own classes, but this is what i have for my FMYPlayers Class .  Also it dont have to be 6 , it could be up to 20.. i been trying to redo this so you could select x amount of players not just 6..just have not made it to this part yet.

Comment: Why is a player represented by a `TStringList`? Wouldn't it be better if you used a class/record instead?

Comment: i use stringlist, cause depending on the player name selected, it reads in all the stats from an ini file for that player.  Been trying to make a game, not sure on using records for this..

Comment: Not records. Objects.  See whosrdaddy's answer. You make objects that represent either (a) real world concepts (a player of your game) or (b) sensible objects via the rules of OOP. Start with (a) and eventually you'll start understanding (b).  Read some delphi books!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a real answer but expanding on what Warren P suggested. Looks like your classes are not correctly designed from the ground up.

```
uses Generics.Collections;


TPlayer = class
 // add player related properties & routines here
end;

TGame = class
 protected  
   // all fields go here
   FPlayers : TObjectList<TPlayer>;

 public

   function AddPlayer(settings : TStringList) : TPlayer; 

   property Player[index:Integer]:TPlayer read GetPlayer;
end;
```

Comment: ok i edited my player class, but not i get errors as iam not sure i did it right.  of course on this line  "property Player: array[1..20] of TStringList read P;
"   i get error idntifer expected but array found, and incompatible types tstringlist and array[1..20] of tstringlist

Comment: forget about array and use TObjectlist instead

Comment: never used that, how would i add that to my player property?

Comment: I edited whosrdaddy's answer - you should declare a property called Player which is indexed.  Then you can write Game.Player[3] which Delphi translates to Game.GetPlayer(3). You have to write GetPlayer method. See if you can figure that out! :-)

Comment: also use `default` indexer property;