# E2008 Incompatible types on an indexed property declaration in Delphi

Tags: delphi, class

Further to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765722/indexed-property-in-delphi-beginner-is-making-multiple-player-objects-accessib), When I try to compile this I get the error incompatible type on this line:

```
    Property player[i : integer] : TStringList read p;
```

I'm unsure why? Here is whole class:

```
unit Battle;

interface

uses
  SysUtils,Dialogs,Classes,inifiles, StdCtrls;
type

  TPlayers = class
  Private
    p : array[1..20] of TStringList;
    FPlaceUnit: Boolean;
    FTeamCount: Integer;
  Public
    Property player[i : integer] : TStringList read p;
    property PlaceUnit : Boolean read FPlaceUnit write FPlaceUnit;
    procedure AddPlayer (PlayerNo : integer; player : String);
    property TeamCount : Integer read FTeamCount write FTeamCount;

    constructor Create;   virtual;
  End;


{Host class}
  THostPlayers = Class(TPlayers)
  Private
    FIsHost: string;
  Public
    constructor Create; override;
    property IsHost : string read FIsHost write FIsHost;
 End;


{Guest Class}
  TGuestPlayers = Class(TPlayers)
  Private
    FIsGuest: string;
  Public
    constructor Create; override;
    property IsGuest : string read FIsGuest write FIsGuest;
  End;

implementation

uses
main;
{constructor}
constructor TPlayers.Create;
begin
  p := TStringList.Create;
end;
constructor THostPlayers.Create;
begin
  inherited;  // Calls TPlayers.Create
  IsHost := 'No';
  PlaceUnit := true;
  TeamCount :=0;
end;
constructor TGuestPlayers.Create;
begin
  inherited;  // Calls TPlayers.Create
  IsGuest := 'No';
  PlaceUnit := true;
  TeamCount := 0;
end;

{ADD Player}
procedure TPlayers.AddPlayer(PlayerNo : integer; player : String);
  var
      CharINI : TIniFile;
  begin
      CharINI := Tinifile.Create(thisdir+'\char\charstats.ini');
      CharINI.ReadSectionValues(player,player[PlayerNo]);
      CharINI.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the property 'returns' a TStringList and field p is an array of TStringlist so that's why you get the incompatible types error.

You would expect that:

```
// This is not working
Property player[i : integer] : TStringList read p[i];  // Not supported...
```

fixes this. But you can't access array elements directly so you need a getter function:

```
TPlayers = class
private
  function GetPlayer(i: integer): TStringList;

public
  Property player[i : integer] : TStringList read GetPlayer 
end;



function TPlayers.GetPlayer(i: integer): TStringList;
begin
  Result := p[i];
end;
```

Comment: ok I tried this but now i get error that error expected ; but got : after the  second : in "getplayer(i:integer): tstringlist; "

Comment: ahh nm , its function instead of procedure.. :D

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate. Please don't post each syntax error you get every day as a new question Glen.  :-)